# Update Records in TargetTable from Source Table with Identical Name Records

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-update

I'm trying to update TableA with records from TableB but only where there are no records in TableA already existing with the same Name Column value. I have queries that will do that however what I'd like to do is in the cases where a 'matched' record exists but does not have values in Fieldx/y/z the existing record will update. For instance:

- Target Table | Bob | NULL     | NULL|
- Source Table | Bob | New York | Doctor

The Target table would not have a new record created since 'Bob' exists but that existing record would have New York and Doctor added since those fields are NULL or empty/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `on duplicate key update` option to `insert`.  First create a unique index on `name`, so duplicates are not allowed:

```
create unique index TargetTable_name on TargetTable(name);
```

Then:

```
insert into TargetTable(name, col1, col2)
    select name, col1, col2
    from SourceTable
    on duplicate key update col1 = coalesce(TargetTable.col1, values(col1)),
                            col2 = coalesce(TargetTable.col2, values(col2));
```

Comment: That is excellent thank you. I am trying to create the unique index and it turns out there are dupes already. Not sure whether to post this as a different question but now I need to find dupes and keep the ones that have values in specified fields and get rid of the others. Conversely I need to make sure the ones I get rid of arent referenced by other records with the ParentID field. I didn't realize this table was such a mess internally but it is all I have to work with.

Comment: @MarkH . . . Ask that as a separate question, along with sample data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Will do thank you for your help marking this as answered by you.